# How to run DITA-OT within a JAR packaged using Maven?

Tags: maven, dita-ot

I have added the `org.dita-ot.dost` dependency from Maven Central, and also manually ran `mvn:install` to install `dost-configuration.jar` from the DITA-OT download as this JAR isn't included.

Then added DITA-OT 3.7.3 as a resource (excluding the `lib` directory) and attempting to make use of it through the Java API.

The issue is you need to supply a `File` pointing to the DITA-OT directory (https://javadoc.io/doc/org.dita-ot/dost/latest/org/dita/dost/ProcessorFactory.html), attempting to use this code to access it via a resource path:

`File ditaOtDir = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/dita-ot-3.7.3").toURI());`

However when you call `ProcessorFactory pf = ProcessorFactory.newInstance(ditaOtDir);` this causes `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DITA-OT directory must be absolute at org.dita.dost.ProcessorFactory.newInstance(ProcessorFactory.java:30) ...`

Also attempted to construct the File in a different way, to little success as it causes a different error when calling `run` on the Processor:

```
URL ditaOtDirUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/dita-ot-3.7.3");
File ditaOtDir = new File(ditaOtDirUrl.toString()).getAbsoluteFile();
```

```
Caused by: Basedir /full/example/path/jar:file:/path/to/this.jar!/dita-ot-3.7.3 does not exist 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.setBaseDit(Project.java:858)
 at org.dita.dost.Processor.run(Processor.java:207)
...
```

Am I missing something obvious about how to construct this File or is it just not possible to package our JAR like this with DITA-OT included within it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible, the DITA Open Toolkit needs to be kept as a separate folder as it is not 100% Java (it contains ANT build files, XSLT stylesheets, JAR libraries), it cannot all be packed and run from a JAR library.

I'm linking also to the DITA OT discussion you started on the same theme:
https://github.com/orgs/dita-ot/discussions/4229#discussioncomment-6412606
The last comment on that thread is made by Jarno Elovirta, the main DITA OT developer.